# Nesting actionPerformed()

Tags: java, image, swing, button, user-interface

I'm designing a program that allows users to reserve an airplane flight. When the program first runs, a JFrame opens with two buttons. Depending on which button is clicked, actionPerformed opens new JPanels, etc.

I'm trying to create a tab inside a JTabbedPane that will display two buttons. Clicking either button will lead to a different image, but this section of code is already in a actionPerformed method. How can I find out which button is clicked?

This is the method I used:

```
protected JComponent makeImagePanel(String path1, String path2) 
{
    try{
        JPanel panel= new JPanel(false);
        JButton international= new JButton("International Flights");
        JButton domestic= new JButton("Domestic Flights");
        international.setActionCommand("login");
        domestic.setActionCommand("domestic");
        international.setEnabled(true);
        international.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(path1));
                    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
                }
            });
        domestic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(path2));
                    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
                }
            });
```

and this is where I tried to implement it:

```
JComponent reservation= makeImagePanel("international_1.gif", "domestic_seating.gif");
            overview.addTab ("Reserve a Flight", reservation);
            overview.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionEvent has a method getSource() which will give you the object on which event was fired. Or you can set Global variable to find out which button was clicked. There are many ways to do it.

Regards,
Ravi